# Applescript: How do I set a 'move to' folder based on the filename to sort files into Alphabetical folders?

Tags: applescript, subdirectory

I'm trying to create a 'folder action' that will organise new files added into sub-folders for each letter of the alphabet based on the first letter of the filename.

I wrote the following code which works to move everything added into the subfolder "A" as a starting point, but now I've reached a block.

```
on adding folder items to thisfolder after receiving added_items
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in added_items
    set this_item to (item i of added_items)
    set DestinationFolderName to "A"
    tell application "Finder"
        move this_item to folder DestinationFolderName of thisfolder with replacing
    end tell
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

My dilemma now is how to change `set DestinationFolderName to "A"` to be reactive to the filename of this_item.

I tried `set DestinationFolderName to text 1 thru 1 of filename` and a few other iterations but the issue seems to be finding the filename to extract the first letter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer provided by @vadian, it is never a good idea to move files into sub-folders of folders with attached folder action commands.

For purposes of this script I created a new (move to) folder named “New Destination” on my Desktop, which will contain the subfolders “A”, ”B”, “C” etc…

If the file being moved, for example starts with the letter “D” and there is no corresponding move to destination folder named “D”, within the folder named “New Destination”, Then folder “D” will be created automatically

[SATIMAGE Scripting Addition](http://www.satimage.fr/software/downloads/Satimage411.pkg) Was used in this script in the event that the first letter of the name of the file being moved is lowercase, the corresponding folder that may be created will be changed from lower to uppercase

```
property DestinationFolderName : missing value
property moveToFolder : (path to desktop folder as text) & "New Destination"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in these_items
        set this_item to item i of these_items
        tell application "Finder"
            set fileName to name of item this_item
            set DestinationFolderName to character 1 of fileName
        end tell

        -- SATIMAGE scripting addition is needed for next command
        set DestinationFolderName to uppercase DestinationFolderName

        tell application "Finder"
            set checkExists to moveToFolder & ":" & DestinationFolderName
            try
                if not (exists of checkExists) then
                    make new folder at moveToFolder ¬
                        with properties {name:DestinationFolderName}
                end if
            end try
            move this_item to folder DestinationFolderName of folder moveToFolder with replacing
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are discouraged from moving the file into a subfolder of the folder action folder because at the moment you are creating the subfolder the folder action is triggered again which can cause an infinite loop.

To move the file to a folder which might be created on-the-fly the shell command `ditto` is the preferred solution because it's able to create intermediate directories implicitly.

This code uses a folder `Test` on desktop as the destination location (the trailing slash is crucial) and uses a handler with help of `AppleScriptObjC` to get the uppercased first letter of the file name.

As `ditto` copies the file an extra `rm` line is needed to delete the source file

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

use framework "Foundation"

on adding folder items to thisfolder after receiving added_items
    set destinationFolder to POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "Test/"
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in added_items
        set this_item to item i of added_items
        tell application "System Events" to set fileName to name of this_item
        set prefix to uppercasedFirstCharacter(fileName)
        set destinationFile to destinationFolder & prefix & "/" & fileName
        do shell script "ditto " & quoted form of POSIX path of this_item & space & quoted form of destinationFile
        do shell script "rm " & quoted form of POSIX path of this_item
    end repeat
end adding folder items to


on uppercasedFirstCharacter(theString)
    set cocoaString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:theString
    return (cocoaString's substringToIndex:1)'s uppercaseString() as text
end uppercasedFirstCharacter
```

Comment: that's great, didn't think of the loop effect! Have tried your code and works great for the files but only issue is it is repeating new alphabet folders as subfolders infinitely - any ideas how to amend?

appreciate your response!

Comment: How are the folders suppose to behave? The script creates one subfolder per (first) letter and files and folders are distributed accordingly. The only change you have to make if folders are involved is to write `"rm -r "` to delete the folders recursively.

Comment: ah it seems that if the folders aren't made then it will keep reproducing them - but providing A-Z folders are already made it works perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I can see you've had help with this already, but I wanted to offer another alternative solution, which doesn't use external frameworks or third-party tools (not that there's anything wrong with using these, of course).

I also wanted to comment about the issue of using a watched folder as the root directory in which you create further sub-folders, which I'll do after presenting my script:

```
    property alphabet : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


    on adding folder items to thisfolder after receiving added_items
        
        tell application "Finder" to ¬
            repeat with this_item in the added_items
                get this_item's name
                get the first character of the result
                my capitalise(the result)

                set DestinationFolderName to the result
                
                if not (exists folder DestinationFolderName in folder thisfolder) then ¬
                    make new folder in folder thisfolder with properties ¬
                        {name:DestinationFolderName}
                
                move this_item to folder DestinationFolderName of folder thisfolder
            end repeat
        
    end adding folder items to


    to capitalise(l as text)
        local l
        
        considering case
            set x to (the offset of l in the alphabet) mod 27
        end considering
        
        return character x of the alphabet
    end capitalise
```

You'll notice this script includes a sub-routine (handler) that I wrote called `capitalise()`.  This takes a letter of the alphabet and returns it in its uppercase form using basically just a single line of code.

The added item's name is retrieved, and its first letter is capitalised.  If a sub-folder named using that letter doesn't already exist, one is created, then the added item is moved into it.

It's largely the same as your script, only with the added ability to create a folder on-the-fly using the first letter of a filename.

---

#### On Infinite Regress...

With respect to the fear of infinite loops caused by creating sub-folders in a watched folder, [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) is absolutely correct in highlighting this issue as it potentially could manifest in the way he described.  It's something to look out for when writing a script that involves changing the folder being watched and, typically, the easiest thing to do is to avoid doing that.

However, perhaps there are instances where you *want* or *need* to store files in the folder being watched.  If you were never allowed do this, then the watched folder wouldn't really be serving its purpose as a folder; it's just acting as a **droplet** (a script onto which you drop files and folders to have some actions performed with them).

So, whilst you should definitely *be careful* with using a watched folder in this manner, you can do so quite reasonably with appropriate safeguards in place to prevent infinite regress.  As a simple example, let's say your script only needed to sort *files* and **not** *folders*; the easy solution would be to get the script to ignore any folders it receives.

But, in fact, we don't even need to do that here: we can let it process files and folders equally, and nothing untoward will happen.

Here is the part of the script that creates the sub-folder then moves the item into it:

```
    if not (exists folder DestinationFolderName in folder thisfolder) then ¬
        make new folder in folder thisfolder with properties ¬
                    {name:DestinationFolderName}

    move this_item to folder DestinationFolderName of folder thisfolder
```

Note that sub-folders are always created in the same place: `thisfolder`, which is the folder being watched; it's not trying to create nested folders.  Also not that, if there's a folder that already exists named using the letter being processed, then it won't try and create another.  The last potential worry might come from trying to then `move` a sub-folder into itself.  Well, this can't be done in *Finder*.  It's ***impossible***.  So, the script will silently throw and error, and terminate, which is exactly what we want.

#### Summary

I'm not compelling you to choose one method over another, nor to disregard the salient advice of a skilled programmer such as [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian).

You *can*, however, use your watched folder to store the sorted files in their sub-folders quite safely, *provided* you take care in how you script these things.

Comment: This was really helpful, always good to understand /why/ to do things as opposed to just a solution that works!

The biggest advantage was I could attach the script to a folder on a server which was my end game!

Appreciate all the help @vadian , CJK , wch1zpink